# Reverse proxy s3 with traefik

Tags: amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am trying to reverse proxy to an s3 endpoint via traefik, but when accesing the page I get an `InvalidBucketName` error instead of the `AccessDenied` one when accessing the endpoint directly.

I have the following `traefik.yml`

```yaml
api:
  dashboard: true

providers:

  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

  file:
    directory: /data/t/
    watch: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
  s3:
    address: ":8200"
```

the following `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.10
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
      - "4242:4242"
      - "8200:8200"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/t/data/:/data/t/
      - /root/t/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

and in the `data` folder, the following `dashboard.yml` and `s3.yml`

```yaml
# dashboard.yml
http:
  routers:
    dashboard:
      rule: PathPrefix(`/api`, `/dashboard`)
      service: api@internal
```

```yaml
# s3.yml
http:
  routers:
    to-s3-https:
      rule: Path(`/`)
      entryPoints:
        - s3
      service: s3-service
      tls:
        {}


    to-s3-http:
      rule: Path(`/`)
      entryPoints:
        - s3
      service: s3-service


  services:
    s3-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: https://s3-eu-central-1.ionoscloud.com/
```

Is there a way to do this, or is it impossible because the buckets are accessed via subdomains? I am planning to access the buckets with `boto3` if this works out.